# python: tuple gets converted to list in mysql insert query

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert a tuple into mysql table using python, but tuple gets converted to list in mysql table.

```
settings: {
      'AEROSPIKE_CONN_SETTINGS' : {
        'hosts': [ ('aerospike.qgraph-vpc.io', 3000) ],
        'policies': {
           'timeout': 3000
        }
      }
    }
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='test', passwd='abcd', db='testdb')
cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
insert_query = '''INSERT INTO test_table (`settings`) VALUES ('{}')'''.format(json.dumps(settings))
cursor.execute(insert_query)
cursor.connection.commit()
```

after executing the above code data gets inserted in the following format

```
settings:{ 
  "AEROSPIKE_CONN_SETTINGS": {
    "hosts": [["127.0.0.1", 3000]]
  }
}
```

It should be in the following format

```
settings:{ 
  "AEROSPIKE_CONN_SETTINGS": {
    "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 3000)]
  } 
}
```

what is wrong or how can I insert in the expected format. I am reading the settings from mysql table in some other python component to connect to aerospike.

Comment: Please see this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721363/preserve-python-tuples-with-json

Comment: This question isn't related to Aerospike. The fact that you are storing Aerospike configuration is just circumstantial. I suggest removing the tag. If Aerospike's python client rejects connecting with a list rather than tuple then ask that question separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a tuple in JSON.

Note however, from the point of view of your Python code there is *no practical difference* between a list and a tuple. It's fine to let it be converted.

Comment: yes it does make difference, while connecting to aerospike a tuple is request. I just converted list back to tuple in python code after reading from mysql.