# Python list of numbers is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, api, flask, serialization

I'm writing an API that needs to return an array of numbers to my Frontend.

More specifically, my python Flask API queries a database to return the creation, deletion and last update times for a cluster. This is the list retrieved from the DB: (1547515344323L, 0L, 1566222293827L). I want to deliver this list of numbers to a HTML table.

I'm trying to return this list I've called "event_results" to my frontend like this.

```
event_list = execute_db_query(query)

event_results = event_list.fetchall()
print(event_results)

return json_response({
    "data" : event_results[]
})
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError:(1547515344323L, 0L, 1566222293827L) is not JSON serializable.
```

I've tried `json.dumps(event_results)` and get the following error:

```
TypeError "should be str and not integer"
```

I really appreciate any help or advice on this. Thanks guys, trying to gain experience in web development.

Comment: `tuple` is not json serializable. Will post the relevant SO question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721363/preserve-python-tuples-with-json

Answer (score 0):

Your `event_results` is not a list, but can be easily turned into one. A simple beginner way to do that would be:

```
list = []
for item in event_results:
    list.append(item)
```

And then you use that in your response. This assumes that what you posted as the list is exactly what the query returns though.