# Pythonic way to accept a tuple in a JSON argument

Tags: python, json, command-line, parameter-passing

I have a script which accepts, on the command line, arguments to create a [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) object.

Typical arguments that could be passed to the `Rectangle` constructor might be something like (in Python, without argument parsing):

```py
patches.Rectangle(
    xy=(15000,0),
    width=9.4,
    height=4,
    color='peachpuff'
)
```

The user can encode this on the command line like so:

```
--patches '[{ "x" : 15000,"y" : 0,"width" : 9.4,"height" : 4,"color" : "peachpuff"}]'
```

This json array is loaded with `json.loads`. Note that *most* of the arguments can just be passed directly through to the `Rectangle` constructor, but the `xy` tuple causes a problem: `json.loads` will never generate a tuple type, so you can't create a tuple this way.

To work around it, I have the user pass separate `x` and `y` mappings, and then combine them like this:

```py
p.add_argument('--patches', help='A JSON array of patches.Rectangle object arguments to patch onto the chart',
    type=json.loads)

# stuff

# put some patches on
if args.patches:
    def from_json(json):
        ret = dict(json)
        del ret['x']
        del ret['y']
        ret['xy'] = (json['x'], json['y'])
        return ret
    for pjson in args.patches:
        p = from_json(pjson)
        ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(**p))
```

Half of that code (essentially all of `from_json`) is just dealing with the transformation of `x` and `y` args into the `xy = (x, y)` tuple.

**Any more elegant/Pythonic way to deal with this?**

It might involve cleaner handling of the json input, or perhaps passing something other than json on the command line (but it must have rough feature-parity with the current approach).

Comment: Tuples in json are typically represented using arrays. Couldn't you just use that? Plus it probably doesn't strictly have to be a tuple, just some iterable with 2 values.

Comment: The elegant/Pythonic way would be to not care if it's specifically a tuple, as @JeffMercado commented, but just some two-element sequence.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721363/preserve-python-tuples-with-json)

Comment: @JeffMercado - I am such an idiot, I didn't think `Rectangle` could accept a 2-element list rather than a tuple, but it can, no problem.

Comment: Anyone feel free to write an answer that points out that `Rectange(xy=[15000, 0], ...` is equally valid :).

Comment: You could also do some sort of `ast.literal_eval` if you really want python syntax for the dictionary in your scripts args

Comment: I don't know about Pythonic, but requiring the user to pass in a specific JSON structure as an option argument definitely feels tortured. Is there a reason you don't simply allow `--width 123` and `--height 42` etc, and supply sane defaults for any unspecified options?

Comment: @tripleee - it's a bit tortured, but with 20+ possible arguments to Rectangle your approach does not seem scalable. Plus note that it's a json array, since you can pass 0 or more patches, which seems hard with an explicit arg per param.

Comment: But then a file name argument, rather than a string argument, would seem more natural. If you want that file to be standard input (maybe teach Python that `-` means that) you can still inline the JSON if you want to.

Answer (score 4):

Your `from_json` function can effectively be used as a custom type for your `--patches` option.

```
def RectangleArgs(s):
    d = json.loads(s)
    d['xy'] = (d.pop('x'), d.pop('y'))
    return d


...

parser.add_argument('--patches', action='append', type=RectangleArgs)

...

for patch in args.patches:
    ax.add_patch(patches.Rectangle(**patch))
```

Aside from simply massaging the JSON read from the command line, you can do additional validation, raising `argparse.ArgumentTypeError` if you find anything that would cause a problem when you try to use the return value in a call to `patches.Rectangle`.

Answer (score 1):

Your motivating assumption that you need a tuple for the `xy` argument to `Rectangle` is not correct: a 2-element list works just as well, so `"xy" : "[1, 2]"` will work fine.

Pointed out by [Jeff in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59569042/pythonic-way-to-accept-a-tuple-in-a-json-argument?noredirect=1#comment105305929_59569042).